# JSON to Tuple operation in IBM Streams

Tags: infosphere-spl, ibm-infosphere, ibm-streams

Is there a way to convert a JSON string to a SPL tuple type without using JSONtoTuple Operator?
I saw this documentation:
https://developer.ibm.com/streamsdev/docs/introducing-the-json-toolkit/
where they have mentioned a native function for converting tuple to json but not json to tuple.

How do I convert a JSON to Tuple inside a Custom operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

version 1.4+ of the JSON toolkit includes functions that you can call from a custom.
This version must be downloaded from Github, as it is not yet included in the Streams product.

Download the [latest version from Github](https://github.com/IBMStreams/streamsx.json/releases), which is 1.4.4.
Build the toolkit: `cd com.ibm.streamsx.json` and run `ant`.

Then you can use the `extractJSON` function:

`public T extractFromJSON(rstring jsonString, T value)`

Pass the JSON string you want to parse, and a mutable tuple that will contain the parsed result as parameters.

For example:

```
composite ExtractFromJSON {
type

 //the target output type. Nested JSON arrays are not supported.
    Nested_t = tuple<rstring name, int32 age, list<rstring> relatives> person, tuple<rstring street, rstring city> address;


graph
    () as Test = Custom() {
        logic
            onProcess : {
                rstring jsonString = '{"person" : {"name" : "John", "age" : 42, "relatives" : ["Jane","Mike"]}, "address" : {"street" : "Allen Street", "city" : "New York City"}}';

                mutable Nested_t nestedTuple = {};
                println( extractFromJSON(jsonString, nestedTuple));
            }
    }
}
```

This is based on the [ExtractFromJSON sample](https://github.com/IBMStreams/streamsx.json/blob/master/samples/JSONToSPLConvert/com.ibm.streamsx.json.sample.jtos/ExtractFromJSON.spl)
 that you can find in the repo on Github.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @ndsilva, this is exactly I was looking for. Additionally, is JSON to Tuple conversion in general a slow process? I had to use parallelism whenever I used JSONToTuple operator. Is extractFromJSON function faster to use that JSONToTuple operator?